# InnerException {"Invalid object name 'dbo.PlayerSet' ."} Entity Framework 4

Tags: entity-framework

So. I created Model-First Entity Data Model, and then generated database from it. To test it, I tried to make simple insertion:

```
public void AddPlayer(string name)
    {
        _player = new Player();

        _player.Name = name;
        _player.Rank = 1000;

        _ctx.AddToPlayerSet(_player);
        _ctx.SaveChanges();
    }
```

And Error:
An error occurred while updating the entries. See the inner exception for details.

InnerException  {"Invalid object name 'dbo.PlayerSet'. "}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved. I have been using db from App_Data. It didn't work. So I attached it SQL Managment Studio to Database, and then generted new connectionString for my Entity Model. Now it works fine.